# Error when extracting a filename to name other files

Tags: bash, file-handling

I am trying to use FFmpeg to convert a video to images in Bash. I would like to use the videos' filenames to name corresponding images (followed by a integer number).

I was able to do this if I was exporting the files in the same directory:

```
for file in `find . -name "*.mp4"`; do ffmpeg -i $file -q 1 $file'_'%d.jpeg; done
```

However, if I were to export images into a desired directory, I got errors. Sees like the value of $file is not just the file name, but a directory.

what I was trying:

```
for file in `find . -name "*.mp4"`; do ffmpeg -i $file -q 1 ~/testfolder/$file'_'%d.jpeg; done
```

My question is: how could I properly extract just the filename to use here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it like this, as it will work with files containing any special characters (including newlines, which are rarely used but valid in filenames).

```
destdir=~/testfolder/
while read -u 5 -r -d '' file
do
  name=$(basename "$file")
  ffmpeg -i "$file" -q 1 "$destdir/${file}_%d.jpeg" </dev/null
done 5< <(find . -name "*.mp4" -print0)
```

The `basename` command is an external program.  You can achieve the same result with the following lines using only shell expansions :

```
name=${file%/}
name=${name##*/}
```

Comment: Note that you may need to redirect the standard input for `ffmpeg` from `/dev/null` so that it doesn't read from the output of the `find` command.

Comment: I added a file descriptor for the loop, and redirected `ffmpeg` input from `/dev/null`.  Does `ffmpep` actually read from standard input, or is that more of a general precaution?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need neither basename nor a loop for this; 
You can use `-type f` to avoid `find` reporting directories in it's result combined with `-exec` option to execute directly your command.

Something like this should work for all your mp4 files:

```
find . -type f -name '*.mp4' -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i $0 -q 1 $0'_'%d.jpeg' {} \;
```

See a small demo test:

```
$ find . -type f -name 'a*.txt' -exec bash -c 'echo ffmpeg -i $0 ' {} \; 
ffmpeg -i ./a.txt
ffmpeg -i ./a spaced file.txt
ffmpeg -i ./aa.txt
ffmpeg -i ./cheatsheets/awk-cheat-sheet-gv.txt
```

As you can see second file has spaces in the file name, but is handled correctly by `find`.
On the contrary such a spaced file will break with a `for loop`.

If you insist to make this job with a loop , then this must be a while loop as advised by Fred.

As a modification to Fred solution you can avoid the use of basename using the `-printf` capabilities of `find`:

```
while read -r -d '' file;do 
  ffmpeg -i "$file" -q 1 "${file}_%d.jpeg"
done < <(find . -name "*.mp4" -printf %f\\0)
```

`-printf %f` according to man page of `find` prints the file name stripped, and appending `\\0` (null char) after each file name we ensure correct filenames handling even if names contain spaces or other special chars.

Small test:

```
$ while read -r -d '' file;do echo "ffmpeg -i $file -q 1 ${file}_%d.jpeg";done < <(find . -name "a*.txt" -printf %f\\0)
ffmpeg -i a.txt -q 1 a.txt_%d.jpeg
ffmpeg -i a spaced file.txt -q 1 a spaced file.txt_%d.jpeg
ffmpeg -i aa.txt -q 1 aa.txt_%d.jpeg
ffmpeg -i awk-cheat-sheet-gv.txt -q 1 awk-cheat-sheet-gv.txt_%d.jpeg
```

Comment: Hmm - this solution doesn't put the output files into the destination - it writes them straight back into the input folder - I don't think that is what the OP asked for here. I don't think it actually answers the question.

Comment: I don't think that it does not work.  The -exec part of find is not built by me but by OP (`ffmpeg -i $0 -q 1 $0'_'%d.jpeg`). I just included it inside find , nothing more.

Answer (score -1):

The bash command `basename` can be used for this.

In this case the following should list only the files:

```
for file in $(find . -name "*.mp4"); do echo $(basename $file); done
```

You can use `$(basename $file)` in your original code to get the filename only.

```
for file in $(find . -name "*.mp4"); do 
  ffmpeg -i "${file}" -q 1 "~/testfolder/$(basename $file)'_'%d.jpeg"
done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Danny! It works! To clarify, I needed to substitute the ~/testfolder/$file'_'%d.jpeg with ~/testfolder/$(basename $file)'_'%d.jpeg

Comment: Ah yes - I missed that it was used twice. I've corrected that answer now. If it works - can you marked it as the accepted answer please?

Comment: Just did! Thanks again!

Comment: Please note that using a command substitution in a `for` loop will break on any file that contains characters that cause word splitting to operate (e.g. spaces).  Consider using a `while` loop with the `find` command fed to the loop with a process substitution (`< <(find...)`).

Comment: To add to @Fred's valid point: [Do not use `for` to parse command output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).
`basename` is an _external utility_ that you can _call from_ Bash, but it has nothing to do with Bash per se.
Not double-quoting the variable references and command substitutions makes their values subject to word-splitting and globbing.

Comment: This makes sense. I was attempting to answer the question in the context of the OP's code. Thank you for the further reading @mklement0, I'll digest that now.

Comment: @DannyStaple: Understood re focusing on the immediate fix, but I think it's important to at least _call out_ bad practices in the code copied from the OP, or, preferably, show a robust alternative.
As an aside: The first `ffmpeg` operand must be just `"$file"`, because input files that aren't located directly in `.` can't be passed by their filename only.

Comment: Ah good spot - that needs a fix. For my own education, why process substitution and not piping?

Comment: @DannyStaple: You need to @-mention me to be notified of responses. Piping involves subshells, and if you define variables in a subshell, the current shell doesn't see them. Using a process substitution allows you to run `read` in the current shell. Compare `unset var; echo 'hi' | read var; declare -p var` to `unset var; read var < <(echo 'hi'); declare -p var`